# Controllable Mass of Fluid Character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am kind of new to unity,to any kind of engine,actually.
I am trying to find a way to have a controllable mass of fluid,i mean to be able to go forward,back and so on using the arrow keys.
At first i thought about having some kind of mesh filled with simulated liquid but it doesn't really fit for my project....
Long story short, i need to be able to move a droplet of water.

Comment: It would be good to include anything you may have tried before asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with instantiating just a lot of balls (2d or 3d) - as a representation for droplets. You can give them all physics colliders and rigidbody mass and you will be able to control them all, by proximity or individually.
In the future you can replace spheres with some kind of surface-generating algorithm like [metaballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaballs) or [raymarching](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdBBzR)

Comment: Thank you very much,i will give it a try.